# LinkedIn HTTP Error 999 - Request denied

Tags: python-3.x, urllib

I am writing a simple script to get public profile visible without login on LinkedIn.
Below is my code to get the page for beautifulsoup. I am using public proxies as well.

```
import urllib.request, urllib.error
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.linkedin.com/company/amazon"
proxy = urllib.request.ProxyHandler({'https': proxy, })
opener = urllib.request.build_opener(proxy)
urllib.request.install_opener(opener)
hdr = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3218.0 Safari/537.36',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Charset': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9,hi;q=0.8',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive'}
req = urllib.request.Request(url, headers=hdr)
page = urllib.request.urlopen(req, timeout=20)
self.soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read(), "lxml")
```

But it is raising "HTTPError 999 - request Denied" error. This is only for testing purpose till I am getting access via partnership program.

What am I doing wrong? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You did not do anything wrong, LinkedIn blacklist cloud servers ip addresses to prevent "stealing" their data. Questionable practice but this is how it is.